# discord.py Set a command to only work if the user doesn't have a certain role

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to set up a verification command that gives a role upon its use, but I want to set it so the user can only use the command if they don't already have the role. This is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def verify(ctx):
  if str(ctx.guild.id) in verify_roles:
    guild = ctx.message.author.guild
    rolegiven = ctx.message.author.guild.get_role(verify_roles.get(str(guild.id)))
    await ctx.message.author.add_roles(rolegiven)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is to retrieve `rolegiven` at the very beginning of your code. You can then check if the `ctx.author` has this role via [`member.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.roles). Here is a simplified version of the explained.

```py
@client.command()
async def verify(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete() # deletes the message the author sent
    if str(ctx.guild.id) in verify_roles:
        verify_role = ctx.guild.get_role(verify_roles.get(str(guild.id)))
        # check if the role is not in the author's current roles
        if verify_role not in ctx.author.roles:
            await ctx.author.add_roles(verify_role)
            await ctx.send("You have been verified!")
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"You already have {verify_role.name}")
```

[image: Command working as seen here]

Comment: Also, do you know how to delete the command trigger when the command is executed?

Comment: @QuantumCode I edited my question accordingly, but you can just use [`message.delete()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.delete)